# Sometimes, javascript not loaded for a Rails Form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using selectize for some of my forms in a Rails app to enhance the user experience of collection fields.

Sometimes, selectize is not loaded. I have to reload the page or go back and click the link to the form again - and then all works as expected.

I have experimented a lot but wasn't able to find reproducable patterns. Is this a known behaviour, are there any good starting points to debug this weird issue?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors when selectize doesn't load? Or are you using turbo? No one would be able to help without seeing the code.

Comment: thanks. Turbo was the keyword here (as it's rails 6, actually turbolinks but - same problem :)

Comment: See https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent.  You'll have to wrap your calls in `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() { ... });` and not `jQuery.ready` or the native DOM ready event since it needs to run every time turbolinks refereshes the page.